# Inequality involving inradius, exradii, sides, area, semiperimeter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

In the $\Delta ABC$, let $r_a,r_b,r_c$ be the exradii, $S$ the area of the triangle, $a,b,c$ its sides, $p$ the semiperimeter and $r$ the inradius. Show that the following inequality holds:
$$r_ar_b+r_br_c+r_cr_a \ge 2\sqrt3 S+\frac {abc}{p}+r^2.$$
I tried to express the exradii in terms of $p,a,b,c$, but I didn't get to show that the inequality holds.

Comment: You  can consult the book of classical geometric inequalities by D.Mitrinovic Kluwer Academic Press, and it should have all the formulas for you to use. And what have you done? can you post your work ? Do you know Euler inequailty, and Gerretsen's inequality relating $R$ and $r$? I think your inequality might need Gerretsen's  to settle it.

Comment: I expressed $r_a=\frac {S} {p-a}$, I amplified all fractions and the I got stuck. Yes, I know Euler's inequality.

Comment: I suggest that you use Heron formula and to rewrite your inequality in terms of S, R, and r, and some one can take it from there for you.