# Geometric inequality involving the inradius

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

For the $\triangle ABC$, let $T$ be the area of the triangle, $a,b,c$ its sides, $p$ the semiperimeter and $r$ the inradius. Prove the following inequality:
$$p^2\ge 2\sqrt3 T+\frac {abc}{p}+r^2.$$

Comment: The area T is given by the Heron's formula

Comment: what is the inradius ?

Comment: Related (but closed): ["Inequality involving inradius, exradii, sides, area, semiperimeter"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1702803/409). This is a *duplicate* if one notes that $p^2$ on the left-hand side in this question equals $r_a r_b+r_b r_c+r_c r_a$ on the left-hand side in the other question. (The fact that this question has "exradii" in its title, but references no exradii in its body, suggests that maybe this question represents the questioner getting a step further into the problem than the other questioner.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the *[known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Incircle)* $pr=T$, we rewrite the inequality as follows
$$ p^2 - \frac{abc}{p} - \frac{T^2}{p^2} \ge 2 \sqrt{3} T$$
Now, using *[Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)*,
$$ \begin{align*}
\mathrm{LHS} &= \frac{1}{4} (a+b+c)^2 - \frac{2abc}{a+b+c} - \frac{(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}{4(a+b+c)} \\
&=\frac{1}{4} (a+b+c)^2 - \frac{8abc+(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}{4(a+b+c)}\\
&=\frac{1}{4} (a+b+c)^2 - \frac{(a+b+c)\left(2ab+2bc+2ca-a^2-b^2-c^2\right)}{4(a+b+c)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2+b^2+c^2 \right)
\end{align*}$$
So, the inequality becomes 
$$ a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge 4 \sqrt{3} T $$
Let $\gamma \colon \!= \widehat{ACB}$. Then, by the *[Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)*
$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab \cos \gamma $$
By the *[trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_trigonometry)* of the area of a triangle
$$ T= \frac{1}{2} ab \sin\gamma $$ 
The inequality becomes then
$$ 2 \left( a^2+b^2 - ab \left(\cos\gamma + \sqrt{3} \sin\gamma \right) \right)\ge 0$$
And this is true since 
$$\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2 - ab \left(\cos\gamma + \sqrt{3} \sin\gamma \right) &= a^2+b^2- 2 ab \sin\left(\gamma+ \frac{\pi}{6} \right) \\
& \ge a^2+b^2- 2 ab = (a-b)^2 \ge 0
\end{align*}$$
And you can also see that the equality holds iff $a=b$ and $\gamma= \frac \pi 3$, that is when the triangle is equilateral.